# Using same object on multiple levels in call hirachy

Tags: object-oriented-design

For explaining my problem I'll start off with a code example. Imagine this (very simplified) code:

```
public void entryPoint() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.doSomething()
    method1(foo);
}

private void method1(Foo foo) {
    // do a lot of stuff before foo is needed again
    foo.doSomethingElse();
    method2(foo);
}

private void method2(Foo foo) {
    // do a lot of stuff before foo is needed again
    foo.doAnotherThing();
}
```

The `foo` object is created on top level and is needed in multiple other methods in the call hierachy. It is currently solved like above and `foo` is passed through a lot of methods in a deep call hierachy. I think this solution is a little clumsy, so I tried comming up with a better one.

Here are some restrictions I have, mainly because of the framework I find myself in:

- I can't change class `Foo`
- `entryPoint()` is a method to be executed multiple times
- `foo` has to be a fresh object each time `entryPoint()` is called
- I have no control of the enclosing objects lifecycle, which means I can't create a new object each time before `entryPoint()` is called
- I can't do anything in the constructor

The only alternative I was able to come up with, is turning `foo` into a field. But in that case the scope of `foo` is a little more obscure, which opens it up for programming errors regarding the third restriction.

Does anyone have any advice on this? Is there a solution I did not yet consider?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to adopt something like the [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) design pattern. If you were coding in C# you could set up a fluent interface using extension methods. For Java you could do something like this:

```
public void entryPoint() {
    FooChain chain = new FooChain();
    chain.addToChain(new Method0Handler()).addToChain(new Method1Handler());

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    chain.handle(foo);
}

class Foo {
    public void doSomething(){}
    public void doSomethingElse(){}
}

interface FooHandler {
    Foo handle(Foo instance);
}

class FooChain implements FooHandler {
    FooChain addToChain(FooHandler handler){
        // add to list of handlers
        return this;
    }

    public Foo handle(Foo instance) {
        // iterate through list of handlers
        // call handler.handle(instance)
        return instance;
    }
}

class Method0Handler implements FooHandler{
    public Foo handle(Foo instance) {
        // do stuff
        instance.doSomething();
        // do more stuff
        return instance;
    }
}

class Method1Handler implements FooHandler {
    public Foo handle(Foo instance) {
        // do more stuff
        instance.doSomethingElse();
        // do even more stuff
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give it some thought but my first impression is that it is not applicable in my case. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @AndréStannek Is there a specific requirement that it does not address?

Comment: This is where it get's hard to explain with a simple example. Basically the framework I'm in prevents a srict/clean implementation of that pattern. But I've done some rather huge refactoring inspired by your solution today, so it helped a little. I'm still pondering over making my problem (and it's restrictions) more clear for this site :-/

Comment: Understandable. You might also want to look at the website I linked for the other behavioral design patterns. A combination of some of them might help you.